# Sparql to recover the Type of a DBpedia resource

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I need a Sparql query to recover the Type of a specific DBpedia resource. Eg.:

pt.DBpedia resource: http://**pt**.dbpedia.org/resource/Argentina

Expected type: Country (as can be seen at http://pt.dbpedia.org/page/Argentina)

Using **pt**.DBpedia Sparql Virtuoso Interface (http://pt.dbpedia.org/sparql) I have the query below:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?l ?t where {
 ?l rdfs:label "Argentina"@pt .
 ?l rdf:type ?t .
}
```

But it is not recovering anything, just print the variable names. [The virtuoso answer](http://pt.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=pt.dbpedia.org%2F&should-sponge=&query=PREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect+%3Fl+%3Ft+where+%7B%0D%0A+%3Fl+rdfs%3Alabel+%22Argentina%22%40pt+.%0D%0A+%3Fl+rdf%3Atype+%3Ft+.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&debug=on&timeout=).

Actually I do not need to recover the label (?l) too.

Anyone can fix it, or help me to define the correct query?

Comment: How are you constructing your query URL?  For some reason, you've got `default-graph-uri` as `pt.dbpedia.org/` rather than `http://pt.dbpedia.org`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `http` in graph name

I'm not sure how you generated your query string, but when I copy and paste your query into the endpoint and run it, I get results, and the resulting URL looks like:

```
http://pt.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpt.dbpedia.org&sho...
```

However, the link in your question is:

```
http://pt.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=pt.dbpedia.org%2F&should-sponge...
```

If you look carefully, you'll see that the `default-graph-uri` parameters are different:

```
yours: pt.dbpedia.org%2F
mine:  http%3A%2F%2Fpt.dbpedia.org
```

I'm not sure how you got a URL like the one you did, but it's not right;  the `default-graph-uri` `needs to be http://pt.dbpedia.org`, not `pt.dbpedia.org/`.

### The query is fine

When I run the query you've provided at the endpoint you've linked to, I get the results that I'd expect.  It's worth noting that the label here is the literal `"Argentina"@pt`, and that what you've called `?l` is the individual, not the label.  The individual `?l` *has* the label `"Argentina"@pt`.

We can simplify your query a bit, using `?i` instead of `?l` (to suggest `i`ndividual):

```
select ?i ?type where {
  ?i rdfs:label "Argentina"@pt ;
     a ?type .
}
```

When I run this at the [Portuguese endpoint](http://pt.dbpedia.org/sparql), I get these results:

[image: query results]

If you don't want the individual in the results, you don't have to `select` it:

```
select ?type where {
  ?i rdfs:label "Argentina"@pt ;
     a ?type .
}
```

or even:

```
select ?type where {
  [ rdfs:label "Argentina"@pt ; a ?type ]
}
```

If you know the identifier of the resource, and don't need to retrieve it by using its label, you can even just do:

```
select ?type where {
  dbpedia-pt:Argentina a ?type
}
```

```
type
==========================================
http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing
http://www.opengis.net/gml/_Feature
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Country
http://schema.org/Place
http://schema.org/Country
```